# Single post query shows "Cannot return null for non-nullable field" error when multiple post query is working fine

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, graphql, prisma

My query for a single post shows

> Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.author

error message when I include the author field, both from React as well as the Playground.  It's working fine for the `posts` query which queries for multiple posts and is able to retrieve the specific author, but not when I perform a single `post` query.

Client-side schema:

```
posts(query: String, first: Int, skip: Int, after: String, orderBy: UserOrderByInput): [Post!]!
post(id: ID): Post!
```

Query from React:

(gql is the same for `post` and `posts` except for the sorting arguments)

```
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_POST, { 
     variables: {
         id: props.match.params.id
     }
 })
export const GET_POST = gql`
    query Post($id: ID!) {
        post(
            id: $id
        ){
            id
            title
            body
            location
            author{
                id
                firstName
                lastName
            }
        }
    }
`
```

Server-side query:

```
 post(parent, args, { prisma }, info) {
        if(!args.id) {
            throw new Error("No search query input")
        }
        return prisma.query.post({
            where: {
                id: args.id
            }, info})
    },
```

Comment: If your posts query works why not make your single post prisma request to `posts`  also and return the first result from the array. You'd need to async / await .

Comment: @Andrew1325 I'm currently using that method as a work around, but it's not ideal since it returns an array. Plus, I just fail to see why the above method isn't working.

Comment: I mean in your server side function use `prisma.query.posts`, there's really nothing wrong with it returning an array, you still use what it contains in the same way. Also `posts` allows a whole variety of `where` fields while `post` only allows you to search by id. As for why post doesn't work, it must be how your `datamodel.prisma` is setup.